# SeriesCollection array size in PPT VBA

Tags: vba, graph, charts, powerpoint

I am trying to add data labels to all my series in a bar chart but the amount of series varies from chart to chart because this is a function used for many charts.  So, I used a `For Loop` to add them, but I need to determine the size of the SeriesCollection array.  Would there be a function that would do so?  When I try to use `.Size` it gives me an error.

Below is what I tried:

```
With Chart
    For i = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Size
    .SeriesCollection(i).Points(i).HasDataLabel = True
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the stuff in the Chart object model isn't properly hooked up to Intellisense.  You'll notice that you get no suggestions when you type `.SeriesCollection`.

`.SeriesCollection.Count` will give you what you're after, I think.